# Partial differential equation - first integrals with two variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I get stuck every time I encounter an equation like this:

$du=(u+xy)dy$

Where there is the dependent variable $u$ and two independent variables under the same differntial.

I just don't get the trick.
I tried to look at the original system and maybe there was a way to express the equation in different way so i can get rid of one of the variables but i can't find my way around it .

$\frac{dx}{5}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{u+xy}$
edit: I also tried to look for tricks like $xdy+ydx=d(xy)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is$$\frac{du}{dy}=u+xy$$where $x$ is a "constant".

It is separable and using the traditional methods, you should find $$u=c_1\, e^y-x(1+y)$$

Comment: oh i see.
$u_y=u+xy$
So I can treat it as an ODE even if $u$ is dependent on $x$ and $y$ while differentiated by y.

Comment: @MarkElishaev. I guess that it was just a trap.